# How to echo an array returned by a function

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to display a list of items retuned by an array by using do_shortcode(). The problem is I have to use echo statement with do_shortcode and in my function I have to a foreach loop which prepares the array of items I wish to display with do_shortcode().

Here is the code

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[su_accordion]' . hsj_accordion($slugs) . '[/su_accordion]'); ?>

<?php function hsj_accordion($slugs) {
    foreach($slugs as $slug ) {
        echo do_shortcode('[su_spoiler title="' . $slug . '"]' . hsj_product_list($slug) . '[/su_spoiler]');
    }
} ?>

<?php function hsj_product_list( $slug ) {
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'product',
                            'tax_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $slug
                                ) 
                            )
                        );

                        $products = get_posts( $args );

                        $product_list[] = array();

                        foreach( $products as $post ) {
                            $product = wc_get_product( $post );
                            echo $product->get_title();
                        }
                    } ?>
```

Comment: You cannot return an array within a shortcode, this will lead to the array to string convertion error. You need to convert your array to a string and then return that string as output value

Comment: Yes, I got that error earlier and then I used echo in foreach loop which outputs the results but breaks the layout. I will try converting the array to string.

Comment: I will post an example now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return an array from inside a shortcode, this will lead to the following error

> Array to string convertion .....

The output from a shortcode needs to be a string, so you need to convert your array to a string. You also cannot echo anything inside a shortcode, neither can you use functions or template tags inside a shortcode which echos its output. In rare cases where you don't have a choice, you can make use of output buffering, but this should be your last resort

To correctly create a shortcode from your function, you have to do something like this: (*CAVEAT: Utested and only a demo to work from*)

```
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'hsj_product_list' );

function hsj_product_list( $atts )
{

$attributes = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'slug' => '',
    ),
    $atts,
    'my_shortcode'
);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $attributes['slug']
        ) 
    )
);

$products = get_posts( $args );

$output = '';

if ( $products ) {

    foreach( $products as $post ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $post );
        $output .= $product->get_title();
    }

}
return $output;
}
```

As you can see, I have concatenated all the values I need into one string which is set to the variable `$output`. I have also made sure if there are no post that we output an empty string by defining `$output = ''` before we start the foreach loop

You can use it as follow

```
[my_shortcode slug='my-slug']
```

### A FEW NOTES

- You would want to sanitize and validate the user inputs, in this case, the value passed to `slug`
- IMO, if you are going to use `do_shortcode`, then you don't need a shortcode. Simply use the function then and make the necessary changes to the function. This will be faster as shortcodes need to be parsed and prossed first making them slower than just the selfstanding function
- Always check that you have an array value before passing it to a `foreach` loop. If an empty value is passed, this will lead to a PHP warning (a bug). I have already done that in my code above, so be sure to check it out
- The above is just the basics of a shortcode, you should extend and modify and abuse it as you see fit in order to suite your needs

Comment: Perfect answer! Concatenation solved my problem. Just a side thing, I didn't create the shortcode, It was already there basically an accordion. All I am trying to do is to populate that accordion dynamically. I am doing such kind of tricks for the first time, I am a bit unsure if this is the neat way of doing things.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. I see what you mean. I do not know the shortcode you are using, so I cannot comment on that, but if it work as expected, then all is good. Enjoy :-)

Comment: What I would suggest is, read the documentation of the theme/plugin, and if you are unsure about the exact use of the shortcode, contact the author or his support group. They should be able to help you. :-)